# iOS build not display at iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have  upload iOS build for my Application  from xcode before 1 day, but i think 24 hours left my build is not appear at iTunesConnect and i'm not getting an email from Apple,So what to do? please Suggest me.

Comment: Did you add new Privacy keys in your info.plist file like, contacts,photolibrary ? check for camera usage, Location aslo.

Comment: yes, NSPhotolibrary key is added

Comment: at time build upload you can minimise window then error in upload build..try new build upload.

Comment: ok,i'm  try with new Build.

Comment: Also check you have created application metadata, version correctly on iTunes Connet.

Comment: yes,After uploading new build  at ituness ,now apper in Itunes,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all the privacy rights in the info.plist file, before me, and finally succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Check Following things:

1.Did you add new Privacy keys in your info.plist file like, contacts,photolibrary ? check for camera usage, Location also.

2.Also check you have created application metadata, version correctly on iTunes Connet.